# Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ej2-syncfusion

I am trying to excess the html element and want to replace the inner content:-
Here is the code i am trying:-

```
import { RichTextEditorComponent } from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-richtexteditor";

export const handleSignatureSelect = (
  signature: string,
  editorRef: React.RefObject<RichTextEditorComponent>
) => {
  const currentSignature = document.getElementsByClassName("gmail_signature");
  if (currentSignature) {
    currentSignature.innerText = signature;
    return;
  }

  editorRef.current?.executeCommand(
    "insertHTML",
    `<br><br clear="all"><div><br></div><br><div dir="ltr" class="gmail_signature" 
     data-smartmail="gmail_signature">${signature}</div>`
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code should be like this because after using `getElementByClassName` it return an array.

```
  const currentSignature = document.getElementsByClassName("gmail_signature")[0];
  if (currentSignature) {
    currentSignature.innerText = signature;
    return;
  }
```

Comment: You misspell the function name in text (though the code is correct. And `getElementsByClassName` does not return an array; it returns an _array-like_ object, a `HTMLCollection`. The distinction is important because `HTMLCollection` is live (its contents change as the document changes), and it lacks many of the functions defined on the `Array` prototype.